# Callable statement double method error

Tags: java, double, callable-statement

I was able to get value set as double like this using callable statement

```
this.setValue(new Double(cstmt.getDouble(4)));
```

but when I try to write it back like this

```
cstmt.setDouble(4, this.getValue());
```

i get error..

```
compile:
     [exec] com\jack\common\javabean\ExampleBean.java:262: cannot resolve symbol
     [exec] symbol  : method setDouble (int,java.lang.Double)
     [exec] location: interface java.sql.CallableStatement
     [exec]                     cstmt.setDouble(7,this.getValue());
     [exec]                              ^
```

any suggestion what can be done with this

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `this.getValue()` returns a `Double`, it looks like you need to use `this.getValue().doubleValue()` to match the method signature.  It takes a `double` primitive, not a `Double` object.

I guess that you're using Java 1.4 or earlier.  In 1.5 this error should have been hidden by autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Appearently the class of which cstmt is an instance, has no (visible) member function called setDouble (int, java.lang.Double).
Is it possible that it should be setDouble (int, double) and you are passing an instance of java.lang.Double and the routine expects a primitive of type double?